# Count number of changes in lines between two files

Tags: perl, unix, diff

I am looking to get the number of lines that have been changed between two files.
diff/diffstat does not give me the correct result.

For example if file1 looked like-

```
if(x==2){
    System.out.println("TEST");
}
if(y==2){
}
System.out.println("finished");
```

and file2 looked like

```
if(x==2){
    System.out.println("TEST22");
}
if(y==2){
    System.out.println("second");
}
```

We should see that there is a count of one modification.

Any help would be appreciated.

EDIT----

Sorry guys, I understand where your coming from.
So what I want to know is when a line changes so for example 
System.out.println("TEST") -> System.out.println("TEST2");

But we also have a line that has been inserted and another line that has been deleted. 
In diff/diffstat, it counts that insertion and deletion as a modification but I do not want this.

Comment: Three lines differ between your examples.

Comment: I see three differences: a line changed (the 2nd), a line added (after the 4th) and a line deleted (the 6th).

Comment: Are you wanting to count the number of lines changed, or the number of "changes" in some abstract sense? As other comments point out, there are three lines changed in your example. But this could conceptually be one "change". With the right settings, `diff` might print that as one change "chunk" - chunks can be counted with some post-processing of the output... Also, `if (y==2){}` is rather pointless...

Comment: Based on your update - what is your threshhold for the difference between a "changed" line vs. a deletion/insertion? What if `System.out.println("TEST")` was changed to `exit(1)`? Would that be a "changed" line or a deletion/insertion? Generally, `diff` and other tools really only work with deletion/insertions - each "changed" line is usually recognized as deleting the old version and inserting the new version...

Answer (score 1):

The differences are:

```
@@ -2 +2 @@
-    System.out.println("TEST");
+    System.out.println("TEST22");
@@ -4,0 +5 @@
+    System.out.println("second");
@@ -6 +6,0 @@
-System.out.println("finished");
```

If you want to count the group of lines that changed, that's simple.

```
$ diff -u0 file1 file2 | tail -n +3 | grep '^@' | wc -l
3
```

If you count an edit as a removal plus an addition, that's simple too.

```
$ diff -u0 file1 file2 | tail -n +3 | grep -v '^@' | wc -l
4
```

If you count an edited line as a single change, it's more complicated.

```
$ diff -u0 file1 file2 | tail -n +3 | perl -e'
   use strict;
   use warnings;

   use List::Util=min qw( min );

   my $diffs = 0;
   my $dels  = 0;
   my $adds  = 0;

   while (<>) {
      ++$adds, next if /^\+/;
      ++$dels, next if /^-/;

      $diffs += $adds + $dels - min($dels, $adds);
      $dels = 0;
      $adds = 0;
   }

   $diffs += $adds + $dels - min($dels, $adds);

   print("$diffs\n");
'
3
```